# Is there a way in MySQL to loop through nested JSON and update them?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mysql-json

For example, I have a field like the following, and I want to update all the current values to the initial values.

```
 {
 "dataset": {
    "field1": {
      "current": "Customized",
      "initial": "Initial1"
    },
    "field2": {
      "current": "Something else...",
      "initial": "Initial2"
    }
  }
}
```

After updating, it should be like this

```
 {
 "dataset": {
    "field1": {
      "current": "Initial1",
      "initial": "Initial1"
    },
    "field2": {
      "current": "Initial2",
      "initial": "Initial2"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to do this purely in MySQL? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Parse (JSON_TABLE() function), update, reconstruct JSON. For example..

Comment: This is gonna be slow. Like... **really slow**. If you find yourself needing to look _inside_ JSON records in any relational database, it almost always means it's time to start looking at your schema definition and including a few of those fields as part of the table, to maintain along with each INSERT/UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

I search mysql [JSON document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-function-reference.html) there doesn't seem to have an easy function that can replace nested JSON object structure.

We can try to use dynamic SQL with [`JSON_EXTRACT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) and [`json_keys`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-keys) function.

First, we need to find updating fields of key and updated fields and use `json_table` with `json_keys` to get all `field*` which is your updated root node.

- current：updated value.
- initial：updating value.

the result will look like

```
'$.dataset.field1.current', JSON_EXTRACT(col, '$.dataset.field1.initial'),
'$.dataset.field2.current', JSON_EXTRACT(col, '$.dataset.field2.initial'),
'$.dataset.field3.current', JSON_EXTRACT(col, '$.dataset.field3.initial')
```

Then we can try to use [`JSON_REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-replace) from the connect string variable.

> Replaces existing values in a JSON document and returns the result.

so that final script might be like.

```
SET @updateFields= '';

SELECT @updateFields := group_concat(DISTINCT '''$.dataset.',fieldKey,'.current'', JSON_EXTRACT(col, ''$.dataset.',fieldKey,'.initial'')') 
FROM T,
    json_table(
        json_keys(col,'$.dataset'),
        '$[*]' COLUMNS(fieldKey VARCHAR(50) PATH '$')
    ) t;
    
set @sql := CONCAT('UPDATE T SET col = JSON_REPLACE(col,',@updateFields,')');
                
                
PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @sql;
EXECUTE dynamic_statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE dynamic_statement;
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e2889a07bb4e941956693037ce080cdd)